# Как запретить ввод цифр и других знаков кроме букв в edit на delphi 10?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-berlin, edit

Хочу сделать так, чтобы у пользователя не было возможности ввода цифр или знаков в поле `Edit`, в моём случае я создаю `БД`, в которой есть поле `Edit`, с назначением для ввода фамилии.
Заранее скажу, что работаю в `RAD Studio` с `Delphi 10.4`
Спасибо за ликбез по данной теме.

Comment: var Key: char;
Добавил в проект такой код, ошибки не выдаёт< но и действий с edit'ом также никаких не произошло, в чём ошибка?
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);

begin
  if CharInSet(key, ['0'..'9', '.', ',']) then
      Key := #0;
end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно смотреть в сторону события `OnKeyPress`.

В приведенном ниже примере игнорируются нажатие цифр, точки и запятой.

```
begin
  if CharInSet(key, ['0'..'9', '.', ',']) then
      Key := #0;
end;
```

Также не стоит забывать об комбинации клавиш `Ctrl`+`V`, контекстном меню...